# Query: Raster alignment in QGIS (pixels without data)

Tags: qgis, resolution, pixel, nodata, alignment

I would like to know if when aligning rasters of different resolutions in QGIS if it is possible that some areas that do not have data can somehow be modified or interpreted to give an explanation according to what is obtained.

In my case, for a flood risk model I am using InVEST software, 2 of its inputs are two raster layers soil hydrologic group (SOIL_GROUP, pixel size 255, -255) and Land use and land cover (ESA_ LULC, pixel size 10, -10) both correctly referenced.

Note: by default, the SOIL_GROUP layer has some zero data (no data) corresponding to areas such as rivers and lakes.

I have aligned the 2 raster layers so that the created layer is used in the mentioned InVEST model, I have tried to align the SOIL_GROUP layer to the ESA_LULC layer; however, the new created layer SOIL_GROUP_10m appears without data (no data). I assume is because of the absence of SOIL_GROUP data.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way that the pixels that have no data (0) are not taken into account in the alignment, that is, that they could be "blocked" or, by another method of resampling or other similar, could be integrated into the final aligned layer, and if so, how much influence this change has on the final alignment.